# How to fix this issue with multiple textures in Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I want to send multiple texture to fragment shader and than mix them there.
But due to some reason when i run this code only texture2 is showing.Here in my fragment shader even if i just write color=color1; than also i am seeing texure2.

My fragment shader:

```
    static const char* fragmentShaderSource = "\n\
    #version 150 core\n\
    in vec2 Texcoord;\n\
    uniform sampler2D tex0;\n\
    uniform sampler2D tex1;\n\
    out vec4 color;\n\
    void main(){\n\
        vec4 color1=texture(tex0,Texcoord);\n\
        vec4 color2=texture(tex1,Texcoord);\n\
        color=mix(color1,color2,0.5);\n\
        //color=color1;\n\
    }\n\
    ";
```

My Code for multiple texture:

```
    GLuint textures[2];
    glGenTextures(2, textures);
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image;

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE0, textures[0]);
    image = SOIL_load_image("1.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex0"), 0);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE1, textures[1]);
    image = SOIL_load_image("2.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex1"), 1);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

And this is my window loop:

```
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_E)) {
            break;
        }
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

This is my whole Code If needed:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include<gl\glew.h>
#include<GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<SOIL.h>
//////////////////////////////////////
static const char* vertexShaderSource = "\n\
    #version 150 core\n\
    in vec2 position;\n\
    in vec3 inColor;\n\
    in vec2 texcoord;\n\
    out vec2 Texcoord;\n\
    out vec3 Color;                                                              

    void main(){\n\
        Color=inColor;\n\
        Texcoord=texcoord;\n\
        gl_Position=vec4(position,0,1);\n\
    }\n";

static const char* fragmentShaderSource = "\n\
    #version 150 core\n\
    //uniform vec4 fragmentColor;\n\
    in vec3 Color;\n\
    in vec2 Texcoord;\n\
    uniform sampler2D tex0;\n\
    uniform sampler2D tex1;\n\
    out vec4 color;\n\
    void main(){\n\
        vec4 color1=texture(tex0,Texcoord);\n\
        vec4 color2=texture(tex1,Texcoord);\n\
        color=mix(color1,color2,0.5);\n\
        //color=color1;\n\
    }\n\
    ";
//////////////////////////////////////


int main() {
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 620, "Window", nullptr, nullptr);


    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;


    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        return -1;

    GLfloat triangleVertices[] = {
        0.5f,0.5f,1,0,0,1,0,
        0.5f,-0.5f,0,1,0,1,1,
        -0.5f,-0.5f,0,0,1,0,1,
        -0.5f,0.5f,0,0,0,0,0
    };

    GLuint vao; 
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo); 
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangleVertices), triangleVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint elements[] = { 0,1,2 ,3,0,2};
    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    GLint statusVertex;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &statusVertex);
    if (!statusVertex) {
        char buffer[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 1024, NULL, buffer);
        std::cout << "Error Compiling vertexShader:" << buffer << std::endl;
    }



    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    GLint statusFrag;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &statusFrag);
    if (!statusFrag) {
        char buffer[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 1024, NULL, buffer);
        std::cout << "Error Compiling fragmentShader:" << buffer << std::endl;
    }

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(program, 0, "color");
    glLinkProgram(program);//making connection
    glUseProgram(program);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////






    GLint positionAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);

    GLint colorAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(program, "inColor");
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAttrib);

    GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(program, "texcoord");
    glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);

    GLuint textures[2];
    glGenTextures(2, textures);
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image;

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE0, textures[0]);
    image = SOIL_load_image("1.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex0"), 0);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE1, textures[1]);
    image = SOIL_load_image("2.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex1"), 1);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_E)) {
            break;
        }
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As rabbit said, the full code example doesn't match the code samples above. Is it te0 or tex0?

Comment: thanks Rabbid. It was because of GL_TEXTURE_2D. But can you tell me why it was even working in the first place and why was second texture(not first) displaying even though both were wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glBindTexture` takes the texture **target** not the **unit**.

Targets are: GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY (and extension specific targets).

The texture *unit* is passed to `glActiveTexture` and these are GL_TEXTURE0, GL_TEXTURE1 and so on, and is also what the sampler uniform is set to.

---

Change your code to

```
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
--- glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
+++ glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
```

and

```
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
--- glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
+++ glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering..Can you tell me why second texture was displaying not first even though they both had error.

Comment: @Abhishek: Because `glBindTexture` does not accept texture unit tokens, when you called it with the unit tokens, these calls had no effect, which means, you didn't change the texture binding. Without changing the target binding, all texture unit would use the (same target) default binding. So you the second texture image upload would overwrite the first texture uploaded (both on the default target) and hence show up in both texture units.